# Change the default date format for query output

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, format, date-format

I'm running an enormous PowerShell script, which loops through every table and view in my database, and creates *.CSV text files for each table/view, containing the entire dataset.
(`SELECT * FROM <table/view name>`)

Any columns that are `DATE` or `DATETIME` are produced in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`
I need them to come out in the format `YYYY/MM/DD`

There are over 1,200 tables and views, so I can't manually specify the format for each affected column.

Can I change the default output format at the server level?
... or at the database level?
... or at the session level?

Here's my PowerShell code:

```
$server = "myserver"
$database = "mydb"
$tablequery = "SELECT s.name AS schema_name, t.name AS table_name FROM sys.tables t LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id UNION ALL SELECT s.name, v.name FROM sys.views v LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = v.schema_id"

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=600
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()



# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])].[$($Row[1])]"

    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "C:\mydb\$($Row[0])_$($Row[1]).csv"

    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: No there is no global setting to specify the format for datetime results. The database returns a column with a date or datetime datatype. It is up to the client to present it how it would like it formatted.

Comment: You could force this with some ugly dynamic sql. You would need to query sys.columns. Then your select statement would need to specify every column instead of *. You would then wrap each column with a case expression and if the datatype of the column is date or datetime you could use the FORMAT function to get your data in the format you want.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah ... that query would probably be tens of thousands of lines long, for all the tables and columns I'm working with. So that's definitely not an option. :(

Comment: Since PowerShell runs on top of .NET have you considered tinkering with the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` settings to affect the default serialization format for the DateTime objects on the client side?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That looks very promising, I'll have to investigate.

Comment: Since the date format is well known and easy to identify, you can try also using a Regular Expression on the query output, replacing all the dates. See this for a similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305359/regex-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: It wouldn't be that long. You are already looping over each table. It would not add all that much to the query to do look at the datatype of the column.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add this line:

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]"fr-CA"
```

in this way:

```
    ...
    ...
# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]"fr-CA"
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])].[$($Row[1])]"

    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "C:\mydb\$($Row[0])_$($Row[1]).csv"

    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```